# ACF - Repeater shows only last entered row, not all rows from post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have this code inside my functions.php file:

```
while ( have_rows('origin-repiter') ): the_row();
$origin = get_sub_field('origin-rep');
endwhile;


while ( have_rows('destination-repiter') ): the_row();
$destination =  get_sub_field('destination-rep');
endwhile;
```

Here are origin-repiter/destination repiter repeater field name and origin-rep/destination-rep are repeater fields, rows if you want.

My problem is that on frontend of my WP site ACF shows only last input from backend for repeater fields.

Example:

For ORIGIN I entered:

LONDON, PARIS, MOSCOW (three rows) same for DESTINATION but inverse (MOSCOW, PARIS, LONDON).

But on frontend ACF showing only last entry

Origin: MOSCOW & Destination: LONDON

This is a code from functions.php which renders PHP/HTML on frontend for those two fields/snippets:

```
$output .= '<div class="post_offer"><div class="offer-header"><div class="offer-pr"><div class="offer-pr-t"> from</div> <div class="offer-pr-v"><div class=""><div class="offer-pr-c">'.$fcurrency_icon .'</div><span class="price" style="font-size:30px;">'.$fprice.'</span></div></div></div> <h2 class="offer-tl editor-paragraph-tags">'.$ftitle.'</h2></div><div class="offer-rt-rd"><div class="offer-rt-rd-o"><div class="offer-rt-rd-lb">Origin</div><div class="offer-rt-rd-lo">'.$origin.'</div></div><div class="offer-rt-rd-d"><div class="offer-rt-rd-lb">Destination</div><div class="offer-rt-rd-lo">'.$destination .'</div></div><div class="offer-rt-rd-ico"></div></div>';
```

Any help appreciated!!!

ADDENDUM - Whole code:

```
function add_box_post_end($content){
global $post;
$postId = $post->ID;
$title = get_field('title_text', $postId);
$ftitle = ($title != '')? $title :'';
$currency_icon = get_field('currency_icon', $postId);
$fcurrency_icon = ($currency_icon != '')? $currency_icon :'£';
$price =  get_field('price', $postId);
$fprice = ($price != '')? $price :'99';

if( have_rows('origin-destination') ):      /* your_repeater_name corresponds to the name of your repeater field */

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('origin-destination') ) : the_row();

    // or save the sub fields in a variable
    $origin = get_sub_field('origin');
    $destination= get_sub_field('destination');

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;


$zbor_text = (get_field('zbor_text')!='')?get_field('zbor_text'):'';
$rr = get_field('zbor_images');
if(get_field('zbor_images')!=''){
    $zbor_imagess = get_field('zbor_images');
    $zbor_images = '';
    foreach($zbor_imagess as $zbor_image){
        $imgUrl = $zbor_image['url'];
        $imgAlt = $zbor_image['title'];
        $imgLink = ($zbor_image['alt']!='')?$zbor_image['alt']:'javascript:;';
        $zbor_images .= '<a href="'. $imgLink .'" target="_blank" style="display:block;"><img src="' . $imgUrl . '" alt="'. $imgAlt .'" /></a><br />';
    }
}else{
    $zbor_images = '';
}



$cazare_text = (get_field('cazare_text')!='')?get_field('cazare_text'):'';
if(get_field('cazare_images')!=''){
    $cazare_imagess = get_field('cazare_images');
    $cazare_images = '';
    foreach($cazare_imagess as $cazare_image){
        $imgUrl = $cazare_image['url'];
        $imgAlt = $cazare_image['title'];
        $imgLink = ($cazare_image['alt']!='')?$cazare_image['alt']:'javascript:;';
        $cazare_images .= '<a href="'. $imgLink .'" target="_blank" style="display:block;"><img src="' . $imgUrl . '" alt="'. $imgAlt .'" /></a><br />';
    }
}else{
    $cazare_images = '';
}

$inchiriere_masina_text = (get_field('inchiriere_masina_text')!='')?get_field('inchiriere_masina_text'):'';
if(get_field('inchiriere_masina_images')!=''){
    $inchiriere_masina_imagess = get_field('inchiriere_masina_images');
    $inchiriere_masina_images = '';
    foreach($inchiriere_masina_imagess as $inchiriere_masina_image){
        $imgUrl = $inchiriere_masina_image['url'];
        $imgAlt = $inchiriere_masina_image['title'];
        $imgLink = ($inchiriere_masina_image['alt']!='')?$inchiriere_masina_image['alt']:'javascript:;';
        $inchiriere_masina_images .= '<a href="'. $imgLink .'" target="_blank" style="display:block;"><img src="' . $imgUrl . '" alt="'. $imgAlt .'" /></a><br />';
    }
}else{
    $inchiriere_masina_images = '';
}


$transfer_aeroport_text = (get_field('transfer_aeroport_text')!='')?get_field('transfer_aeroport_text'):'';
if(get_field('transfer_aeroport_images')!=''){
    $transfer_aeroport_imagess = get_field('transfer_aeroport_images');
    $transfer_aeroport_images = '';
    foreach($transfer_aeroport_imagess as $transfer_aeroport_image){
        $imgUrl = $transfer_aeroport_image['url'];
        $imgAlt = $transfer_aeroport_image['title'];
        $imgLink = ($transfer_aeroport_image['alt']!='')?$transfer_aeroport_image['alt']:'javascript:;';
        $transfer_aeroport_images .= '<a href="'. $imgLink .'" target="_blank" style="display:block;"><img src="' . $imgUrl . '" alt="'. $imgAlt .'" /></a><br />';
    }
}else{
    $transfer_aeroport_images = '';
}

$escala_text = (get_field('escala_text')!='')?get_field('escala_text'):'';
if(get_field('escala_images')!=''){
    $escala_imagess = get_field('escala_images');
    $escala_images = '';
    foreach($escala_imagess as $escala_image){
        $imgUrl = $escala_image['url'];
        $imgAlt = $escala_image['title'];
        $imgLink = ($escala_image['alt']!='')?$escala_image['alt']:'javascript:;';
        $escala_images .= '<a href="'. $imgLink .'" target="_blank" style="display:block;"><img src="' . $imgUrl . '" alt="'. $imgAlt .'" /></a><br />';
    }
}else{
    $escala_images = '';
}

$button_one_text = (get_field('button_one_text')!='')?get_field('button_one_text'):'CLICK HERE TO BOOK';
$button_one_url = (get_field('button_one_url')!='')?get_field('button_one_url'):'#';
$buttonOne = '<a class="offer-book-lnk" href="'.$button_one_url.'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'. $button_one_text .'</a>';

$button_two_text = (get_field('button_two_text')!='')?get_field('button_two_text'):'HOTEL COMPARISON TOOL';
$button_two_url = (get_field('button_two_url')!='')?get_field('button_two_url'):'#';
$buttonTwo = '<a class="offer-book-lnk" href="'. $button_two_url .'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'. $button_two_text .'</a>';

$zbor = ($zbor_text!='' || $zbor_images!='')? '[tabby title="ZBOR"]'. $zbor_text . '<br />' . $zbor_images:'';
$cazare = ($cazare_text!='' || $cazare_images!='')? '[tabby title="CAZARE"]'. $cazare_text . '<br />' . $cazare_images:'';

$inchiriere_masina = ($inchiriere_masina_text!='' || $inchiriere_masina_images!='')? '[tabby title="INCHIRIERE MASINA"]'. $inchiriere_masina_text . '<br />' . $inchiriere_masina_images:'';

$transfer_aeroport = ($transfer_aeroport_text!='' || $transfer_aeroport_images!='')? '[tabby title="TRANSFER AEROPORT"]'. $transfer_aeroport_text . '<br />' . $transfer_aeroport_images:'';

$escala = ($escala_text!='' || $escala_images!='')? '[tabby title="ESCALA"]'. $escala_text . '<br />' . $escala_images:'';

$output = '';
if(is_single() && $ftitle!='' && $price!=''){
    $output .= '<div class="post_offer"><div class="offer-header"><div class="offer-pr"><div class="offer-pr-t"> from</div> <div class="offer-pr-v"><div class=""><div class="offer-pr-c">'.$fcurrency_icon .'</div><span class="price" style="font-size:30px;">'.$fprice.'</span></div></div></div> <h2 class="offer-tl editor-paragraph-tags">'.$ftitle.'</h2></div><div class="offer-rt-rd"><div class="offer-rt-rd-o"><div class="offer-rt-rd-lb">Origin</div><div class="offer-rt-rd-lo">'.$origin.'</div></div><div class="offer-rt-rd-d"><div class="offer-rt-rd-lb">Destination</div><div class="offer-rt-rd-lo">'.$destination .'</br></div></div><div class="offer-rt-rd-ico"></div></div>';
    $output .= do_shortcode( $zbor . $cazare . $inchiriere_masina . $transfer_aeroport . $escala . '[tabbyending]');
    $output .= '<div class="offer_footer"><!--<ul class="offer-book">
                        <li class="offer-book-it">' . $buttonOne . '</li>
                        <li class="offer-book-it">' . $buttonTwo . '</li>
                </ul>--></div></div>';
}

$content .= $output;
return $content;
```

Comment: Could you check if ACF has saved the values correctly?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what do you mean by this? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code sample does not make much sense, as your are constantly overwriting the values of $origin and $destination.
Furthermore if you want to couple the origin and destination values, you should setup the ACF field as follows: **1 repeater and 2 repeater sub-fields** for origin and destination

To loop through the repeater values in the frontend, use a structure like this:

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('your_repeater_name') ):      /* your_repeater_name corresponds to the name of your repeater field */

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('your_repeater_name') ) : the_row();

        // display the sub field (the function the_sub_field echos the values directly)
        the_sub_field('origin');        /* sub-field with name "origin" */
        the_sub_field('destination');   /* sub-field with name "destination" */

        // or save the sub fields in a variable
        $origin = get_sub_field('origin');
        $destination= get_sub_field('destination');

        // and then echo them
        // you need to output them **INSIDE** the while loop
        echo $origin;
        echo $destination;


    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
```

---

Applied to your scenario, assuming that you have a functions.php and a page-template:

Add this to your **functions.php**:

Note, you have to check that the acf-field-names match the code. The repeater field in the example is called "your_repeater_name".

```
function print_origin_dest(){

    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('your_repeater_name') ):

        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('your_repeater_name') ) : the_row();

            // get the acf values
            $origin = get_sub_field('origin');
            $destination= get_sub_field('destination');

            // add the title and icon html here (you have not defined them in your question)
            $ftitle = 'Your title';
            $fcurrency_icon = '';

            // render the content
            $output = '<div class="post_offer"><div class="offer-header"><div class="offer-pr"><div class="offer-pr-t"> from</div> <div class="offer-pr-v"><div class=""><div class="offer-pr-c">'.$fcurrency_icon .'</div><span class="price" style="font-size:30px;">'.$fprice.'</span></div></div></div> <h2 class="offer-tl editor-paragraph-tags">'.$ftitle.'</h2></div><div class="offer-rt-rd"><div class="offer-rt-rd-o"><div class="offer-rt-rd-lb">Origin</div><div class="offer-rt-rd-lo">'.$origin.'</div></div><div class="offer-rt-rd-d"><div class="offer-rt-rd-lb">Destination</div><div class="offer-rt-rd-lo">'.$destination .'</div></div><div class="offer-rt-rd-ico"></div></div>';

            echo $output;

        endwhile;

    else :

        // no rows found

    endif;
}
```

Then in your page-template, call the function:

```
<?php print_origin_dest(); ?>
```

Comment: HelloI used your approach and created 1 repeater and 2 repeater sub-fields and then save subfields as variable using your code example, but still the same - it shows only last input destination/origin from backend.

Comment: This is my code by your example:

`if( have_rows('origin-destination') ):      /* your_repeater_name corresponds to the name of your repeater field */

     // loop through the rows of data
     while ( have_rows('origin-destination') ) : the_row();

        // save the sub fields in a variable
        $origin = get_sub_field('origin');
        $destination= get_sub_field('destination');

     endwhile;

 else :

     // no rows found

 endif;`

Comment: Now you're doing the same thing again: in each pass of the while loop, you're saving the sub_field value in the variables. You need to display the values **IN** the while loop. I've updated my answer for illustration.

Comment: OMG, I see... But that is my problem. I see you are a very good with ACF so could you help me please then with this:you can see in my question above the code which is used to render HTML on frontend using saved field variables. This code is out of loop, could you advice me with this?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe will be simpler just to show you whole code for whole page with all fields; I will update my question so then I will understand you better

Comment: Thank you very much, I used some of you advices and created what I want to achieve. Thank you a lot...

Comment: I didn't have time to come back to your edit yet. Great that you could do it on your own.